# How to optimize this code so that the whole process can be accelerated?

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve this problem below, from [here](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/distinct-subsequences/) :

> Given two strings s and t, return the number of distinct subsequences of s which equals t.
>
> A string's subsequence is a new string formed from the original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters without disturbing the remaining characters' relative positions. (i.e., "ACE" is a subsequence of "ABCDE" while "AEC" is not).
>
> It is guaranteed the answer fits on a 32-bit signed integer.

It can be solved by Dynamic Programming like this ( which was my first try ):

```
var dp = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: s.count+1), count: t.count+1)
dp[0] = Array(repeating: 1, count: s.count+1)
var sArr = s.map({$0}), tArr = t.map({$0})
for i in 1...t.count {
    for j in 1...s.count {
        dp[i][j] = tArr[i-1] == sArr[j-1] ? dp[i-1][j-1] + dp[i][j-1] : dp[i][j-1]
    }
}

return dp.last!.last!
```

HOWEVER, I ran into this 'Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow' , then i figured out that it was because it can not store an array that is too big , like 1000 * 1000 :(

Then, I optimized this code by letting the `dp`Array store only two lines of the data. like this:

```
if t.count > s.count { print(0); exit(0) }

var dp = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: s.count+1), count: 2)
dp[0] = Array(repeating: 1, count: s.count+1)
//var sArr = s.map({$0}), tArr = t.map({$0})
let sArr = Array(s)
let tArr = Array(t)
for i in 1...t.count {
    for j in 1...s.count {
        dp[1][j] = tArr[i-1] == sArr[j-1] ? dp[0][j-1] + dp[1][j-1] : dp[1][j-1]
        dp[0] = dp[1]
        dp[1] = Array(repeating: 0, count: s.count+1)
    }
}

print(dp.last!.last!)
```

HOWEVER, this time it still spend too much time on a 1000 * 1000 array.

So, is there anything that I can do to accelerate the whole process so that I can spend less time on this huge array test example.

- test example is like this

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Also, sorry I can't really give a specific time limit, all I want to know is there is any way I can optimize this process.

> BTW, I also wrote it in Python which passes all the example smoothly.
> Swift is slow ;(

Comment: "Swift is slow" Swift is at least 7 times faster than python!!!

Comment: wow,  didn't see that come. Maybe it has to be in situation I stated that swift is far more slower than Python :).